# Most MySQL-like hibernate-compatible in-memory database?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, unit-testing, h2

For a project I am working on(Spring/struts 2/hibernate), we decided to use h2 for unit testing with MySQL for the production store and manage the scheme in liquibase, pretty standard fare, but the issue we keep on running into is that h2 and MySQL differ in a lot of ways, for example how they handle timestamps and triggers.  It's getting to the point that I am starting to regret using h2 as the extra headaches the mis-matches are causing are starting to outweigh its benefits.  My question is this, is there any other in-memory/local file database that behaves more like MySQL?  Obviously for integration testing we will still use MySQL, but being able to do unit testing without either making the liquibase files into a giant hack or having to ensure the local MySQL db is running would be nice.

Comment: So you're ready to make the same mistake a second time, only to discover other incompatibilities? I would use MySQL. It's light and fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is another in-memory Java database that is more compatible to MySQL than H2. If you have a lot of code that only works with MySQL, then you should probably also use MySQL for testing.

Just be aware that it will be difficult in the future to switch to another database. Relying too much on features of one product will result in a ["vendor lock in"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vendor_lock-in). In case of MySQL at least you have the option to switch to [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/), so it's not all that bad.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a ram drive, copy your testing tables and datas into that drive, and start your mysql configured to load from that drive, all that in a script at boot time.

Then your unit tests will run insanely faster. We used it for developpers workstations and the level of frustation went three steps down.

Answer (score 0):

I think that as of right now the correct approach is to use MySQL as a Docker image.

Once you create the image you can easily spin it up from your tests, and it's going to take seconds. Your hibernate will dynamically initialize DB schema and there you go!

The only issue is that CI servers need to have Docker installed.